# Auto-Populate a Lookup Field without Saving? Is This Possible?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, case, lookup

is it possible to auto-populate a lookup field without saving the case record type? (without code/via config)

**Scenario:**

Case Record Type.

-User uses lookup field 'Client Product' to select a product.
-Upon selection *and without saving*, a Picklist Field called 'Case Product' auto populates *XYZ Value* depending on what the user selected as the 'Client Product'.
-('Case Product' is a global value set.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Workflow and Process Builder only triggers on a successful save. You would necessarily need to write code. Picklist values can only depend on other picklist values and checkbox fields.

Comment: That's what I thought, Thanks Fox.